# How do I avoid using a million view controllers for tableview list?

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiviewcontroller

Here's an example of what I want to do.

You have a table view with a list of different videos. When you click on a video it takes you to a detailed view controller (video at the top, description below). Right now I currently create a brand new view controller, add the video/text, link the segue, and then create another view controller and start over. Instead of having a million view controllers, can't you do this with just one view controller and feed in the text/video from a swift file? I am relatively new so if someone could explain the process crystal clear it would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need one VC to display the many videos you have.

Let's say you have a model like this:

```
struct Video {
    let videoLink: URL
    let description: String
}
```

And your table view controller uses an array of `Video`s called `videos` as its data source.

In your `didSelectRowAt` method, you can get the selected video and perform a segue with the selected video as the sender:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let videoSelected = videos[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "showVideo", sender: videoSelected)
}
```

Now create a single `VideoViewController.swift` file and do something like this:

```
class VideoViewController: UIViewController {
    var video: Video!

    // write code for this VC to display not a specific video, but "self.video"
    // For example, instead of setting the label's text to a hardcoded description, set it to "self.video.description"
}
```

Then, go back to your table view controller, and override `prepareForSegue`:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? VideoViewController {
        vc.video = sender as! Video
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes , you can do it with 2 vcs ( the list & detail ) only , by doing this ( known as **Dependency Injection**)

```
let vc = YourTableVC()
vc.arr = // set arr here
present///
```

---

```
class YourTableVC : UITableViewController {
  var arr = [YourModel]()
}
```

Where the model

```
struct YourModel {
  // add properties
}
```

same idea applies to navigation from list to detail

Comment: I will have to look more into Dependency Injection, but pretty sure this answers my question! Thanks!